# How to bypass required fields in vf page

Tags: visualforce, required-field

I have the below vf page where i am getting the required fields error if i dont fill the field and press the command button.

[image]

I want to make both the section independent.How to do it. Below is my vf page code -

```
<apex:page standardController="RFP__c" extensions="RFPController" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false"  docType="html-5.0">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:pageBlock id="pb">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Business RFP Details" columns="1" collapsible="false">
                <apex:inputField value="{!accounts.Name}" required="true"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>   
            <apex:outputText rendered="{!isRerender}">
            </apex:outputText>      
            <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!0}"/>
            <apex:outputPanel id="rows">
                <apex:actionRegion id="ignoreApply">
                    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Child RFP Details" collapsible="false" id="section">
                        <apex:pageBlockTable id="thetable"  var="acc" value="{!attendeeList1}" onRowMouseOver="removeHighlight(this)">
                            <apex:column headerValue="Custom Package">
                                <apex:param name="rowIndex" value="{!rowNumber}"/>
                                <apex:selectList multiselect="true" value="{!acc.discountSchedule}"  styleClass="fullWidth chzn-select" size="1" style="width:400px;" id="cp" >
                                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!acc.updateMarketOptions}" rerender="geographies" oncomplete="renderChosen()" status="statusSaveTrip"/>
                                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Items}"/>
                                </apex:selectList> 
                                <apex:variable var="rowNumber" value="{!rowNumber+1}"/> 
                            </apex:column>

                        </apex:pageBlockTable>
                    </apex:pageBlockSection>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!addblankRow}" value="Add Blank Row" reRender="ignoreApply" oncomplete="renderChosen()" > 
                        <apex:param name="rowIndex" value="{!rowNumber}"/>
                    </apex:commandButton>  
                </apex:actionRegion>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: r u getting error when clicking on Add Blank Row button

Comment: I have displayed  it in pic above...Its asking to fill the required field..I want it shouldnt ask, but that field should be required..

Comment: Can you take more concise screenshots that don't take up a bunch of blank vertical space?

Comment: That's not a standard Salesforce required field validator being shown in the screenshot. Do you have a JS library in this page that is enforcing validation on required fields?

Comment: If you want independent sections then give them independent <apex:form> tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding immediate = "true" attribute to Commandbutton

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!addblankRow}" value="Add Blank Row" reRender="ignoreApply" oncomplete="renderChosen()"  immediate ="true"> 
                            <apex:param name="rowIndex" value="{!rowNumber}"/>
                        </apex:commandButton>
```

Comment: No Luck.. same problem

Comment: @Sid remove commandbutton logic and paste it outside outpanel

Comment: I am still getting the same error. if i place it outside outpanel..

Answer (score 0):

I think that these are browser specific validations because your document type is HTML5.

You can either remove

```
required=true
```

From your input field or add a pass through attribute in your apex:form

```
<apex:form html-novalidate="novalidate">
```